# apache2 or apache2-mpm-prefork, which one is more secure?

Tags: security, debian, webserver, apache-http-server

From a pure security perspective, and on a Debian (or derivative, such as Ubuntu) system, what should one be installing as a web server?

- *apache2*

> sudo apt-get install apache2

OR

- *apache2-mpm-prefork*

> sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork

Which one is the more secure option, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apache2` package is used to select the other packages you need as part of the Apache installation.  `apache2-mpm-prefork` defines which 'processing model' will be used (`prefork` in this case).  The other options are `apache2-mpm-event`, `apache2-mpm-itk` and `apache2-mpm-worker`.

One is not necessarily more (or less) secure than another, as the differences between each are in how they handle setting up to receive new requests - `MPM` == `Multi-Processing Module`.

For most uses the `apache2-mpm-worker` MPM is appropriate.

If you use `aptitude` on your Debian system, when you select the `apache2` package, `apache2-mpm-worker`, `apache2-utils` and `apache2.2-common` will be selected for you automatically (along with any other support packages which are not already installed on your system).  Similarly:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Will install `apache2`, `apache2-mpm-worker`, `apache2-utils` and `apache2.2-common`.